# Visual C++/MySql App is locked on other computers

Tags: mysql, database, visual-c++

I have made a simple database on MySql and am accessing it on a visual c++ GUI using the following code for example:

```
String^ constring=L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3307;username=BilletData;password=root";
MySqlConnection^ conDataBase=gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase= gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from database.materials ;", conDataBase);
MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
```

This runs fine on the computer on which I have MySql installed and am running the code from however when I send the app to other computers which do not have MySql and run the code a little padlock symbol appears on the bottom left of my desktop icon for the app and when I run it I get a couple second delay and then a message appears saying "program has stopped working" and has a loading bar underneath it (same as when something crash's for example when internet explorer crash's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasource points to 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback address.  It will locate mySQL fine if running on the same hosts as mySQL, but not on any other machine. If the program needs to run on hosts other than the one where mySQL is located, the datasource needs to use the external network address for the mySQL machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, could you please help me find my external network address?

Comment: Assuming you are running on windows, ipconfig /all will show all the network interfaces. The external address which the other host(s) can see is likely to be something like 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x

Comment: It's likely to be the value for the "IPv4 Address" for the first adapter returned

Comment: I have just tried it, used the IPv4 Address under my Wireless LAN Adapter, worked fine on the laptop which I have MySql on but when I sent the app to my other computer I got the same error with the padlock. The other computer is running off of the same wireless connection, will this cause any problems?

Comment: The problem may then be that mySQL only binds to the loopback address, which is the default configuration.  You need to change the mySQL configuration or startup so that it binds to address 0.0.0.0. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address